Artifacts on external display during dGPU passthorugh to VM
I couldn't find a problem like this anywhere. I've tried dozens of times from various guides to redirect dGPU to VM and in the best case, during startup I receive boot information and artifacts on the external monitor. Screenshots:

everything looks ok at the installation menu: Installation screenshot
after selecting the first option: first option screenshot

I want to mention that it happens randomly that when starting/shutting down the VM, the image on the integrated monitor completely freezes.
I was trying to follow these guides carefully, step by step:

Ubuntu 22.04 GPU passthrough (QEMU)
https://gitlab.com/risingprismtv/single-gpu-passthrough/-/wikis/home

But I ended up with the same result.
Environment specification:

Laptop: HP ZBook Fury G7 Mobile Workstation - dGPU: Nvidia Quadro T2000 Max-Q
Host OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4, kernel: Linux 6.5.0-28-generic
Guest OS: Same as host OS
Virtualization tool: virt manager
Parameters added to grub: intel_iommu=on iommu=pt
External monitor connected via HDMI. (Only dGPU supports output, so the running host shows nothing on the external monitor)
Graphics loading modules disabled by creating a file /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf with content: vfio content screenshot
All devices from the dGPU IOMMU group except PCI Bridge were added to the VM
lspci -nnk before starting the VM:
lspci exec screenshot before
lspci -nnk after shutting down and during the running VM:
lspci exec screenshot after
VM configuration: https://pastebin.com/YvKhVncL

I want to achieve a state where I can use iGPU on the host and isolate dGPU for the VM. At this moment, I can't separate the graphics cards so that the integrated one supports the integrated monitor and the dedicated one for the external monitor.
Does this problem have anything to do with the MUX switch (I don't know if it's even there)?
The laptop allows a lot, as it is the workstation in the best version of the G7 model. I tried to find something interesting in the BIOS but the only setting related to this I found was preferred graphics card: auto (tried), UMA, discrete graphics, hybrid graphics (tried).
